# How to show $(G/N)' = NG'/N$

Tags: group-theory

How to show $(G/N)' = NG'/N$ where $G' = \text{commutator of the group G}$, and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Can you show that one side of the claimed equality must be a subset of the other? Have you tried either direction separately?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes that is what I am trying to do. which side of the claimed equality is a subset.

Comment: Both sides of the claimed equality are subsets of $G/N$. Both sides are also subgroups (surely results implying tha have been covered in your course). We can take advantage of this fact as follows. Show that generators of the group on the left belong to the group on the right. The inclusion $\subseteq$ then follows (can you see why?).

Comment: Then write a generic element of the group on the right, and show that it belongs to the group on the left. This gives you the reverse inclusion, and hence the claim.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I saw somewhere $G'N/N$ instead of $NG'/N$. Does this violet the claim? Thanks.

Comment: @Babak: No. $N$ is normal (as is $G'$), so $Ng=gN$ for all elements $g\in G$. In particular, when $g\in G'$ :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have a commutator of $G/N$. This is:

$(Na)(Nb)(Na)^{-1}(Nb)^{-1} = (Na)(Nb)(Na^{-1})(Nb^{-1}) = Naba^{-1}b^{-1}$

Since this is equal to: $N(e)(aba^{1-}b^{-1})$ with $e \in N$ and $aba^{-1}b^{-1} \in G'$, every commutator of $G/N$ is an element of $NG'/N$, so by closure, $(G/N)'$ is contained in $NG'/N$.

On the other hand, given $N(ng) = Ng \in NG'/N$, we have from $g \in G'$ that:

$g = (a_1b_1a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1})(a_2b_2a_2^{-1}b_2^{-1})\cdots(a_kb_ka_k^{-1}b_k^{-1})$ so that:

$Ng = N[(a_1b_1a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1})(a_2b_2a_2^{-1}b_2^{-1})\cdots(a_kb_ka_k^{-1}b_k^{-1})]$

$ = (Na_1b_1a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1})(Na_2b_2a_2^{-1}b_2^{-1})\cdots(Na_kb_ka_k^{-1}b_k^{-1})$

$ = (Na_1Nb_1(Na_1)^{-1}(Nb_1)^{-1})(Na_2Nb_2(Na_2)^{-1}(Nb_2)^{-1})\cdots(Na_kNb_k(Na_k)^{-1}(Nb_k)^{-1}) \in (G/N)'$

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach (in particular for the first direction). Take

$$\overline x,\overline y\in\left(G/N\right)/\left(NG'/N\right)\cong G/NG'$$

Thus, we get that

$$\overline x\overline y=\overline y\overline x\Longleftrightarrow \overline {x^{-1}}\,\overline{y^{-1}}\overline x\overline y\in NG'\;\;\;(**)$$

Putting $\,\overline x=aN\;\;,\;\;\overline y=bN\,\,,\,\,a,b\in G\,$ , we have that   $\,(**)\,$ is true iff

$$a^{-1}b^{-1}abN:=[a,b]N\in NG'=G'N$$

But since $\,G'\,$ is generated by elements of the form $\,[a,b]\,\,,\,\,a,b\in G\,$ , then $\,(**)\,$ is true indeed, and this means $\,\left(G/N\right)/\left(NG'/N\right)\cong G/NG'\,$ is abelian, and this happens iff $\,\left(G/N\right)'\leq NG'/N\,$ ...

For the other direction: let $\,xN\in G'N/N\,\,\,,\,\,x=cn\,\,,\,\,c\in G'\,,\,n\in N\Longrightarrow$

$$xN=cnN=cN=(c_1\cdot...\cdot c_m)N\;\;,\;\;c_i=[a_i,b_i]\,\,,\,\,a_i,b_i\in G\Longrightarrow$$

$$xN=\prod_{i=1}^mc_iN\in\left(G/N'\right)\,\,,\,\text{since}\,\,c_iN=[a_i,b_i]N\in\left(G/N\right)'\,\,,\,\forall i=1,...,m$$

Comment: Nice answer, Don

Answer (score 0):

If $f: G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism, then $f(G') = f(G)'$. This follows from the fact that $f([a,b]) = [f(a), f(b)]$. Thus when $f$ is the natural homomorphism $f: G \rightarrow G/N$, we get $$(G/N)' = f(G)' = f(G') = NG'/N.$$

More generally, you can show that $f(G^{(n)}) = f(G)^{(n)}$, where $G^{(1)} = G' = [G,G]$ and $G^{(k+1)} = [G^{(k)}, G^{(k)}]$. Using this you can prove many basic facts about solvable groups.